# Why had not CV been based on Semaphore when it was being implemented on Linux?

Tags: c++, gcc, semaphore, condition-variable

Recently, I need a method in my program to notify a thread in another. Of course, I want it goes faster and more stably. So I compared the condition_variable in the STL with the POSIX-Semaphore of the Linux. I'm using gcc-8.2.0 and its libs. The codes attached later.

the results is:

> Avg delay of CV notification is :10.752us 
>   StD is:3.911us
>   Max delay is:473us
>   Min delay is:5us
>
> Avg delay of Semaphore notification is :10.307us
>   StD is:5.768us
>   Max delay is:537us
>   Min delay is:4us

The performance of both are similar, but I think at least Semaphore has 3 advantages as following:

1. No spurious waking.
2. No notification leaking.
3. No lock/mutex must be used.

My question is:
Why CV spuriously wakes up, eventhough a Semaphore never do so?
Why had not CV been based on Semaphore when it was being implemented on Linux?
Semaphores can not be used when CV was implemented on Linux?

About the second advantage of Semaphore:
We must call the wait/wait_for/wait_until of CV before the executing of notify_one/notify_all, or the notification would be lost, but it is hard to be ensured in real works.
Imaging a simplest scene with only one productor and only one consumer: When the productor is sending notification, the consumer might be listenning on, or might be processing the data comed with earlier notifications. This is a very very normal situation, but CV's method can not work with it smoothly.

Semaphore can work perferctly in this situation. Whenever you sem_post a notification, it always waits for you untill you call sem_wait. Just likes that "How many you put, is how many you can get".

I know the wait_for/wait_until func of CV can accept a timeout argument, that give us a chance to re-work after losing a notification instead of to keep waiting stupidly, but it is not yet an event-mechanism likes "notifying/responsing", rather likes a busy-checking loop, and will unnecessarily consume more cpu time. When running my test, I really observed a higher cpu usage of CV than that of Semaphore.

The experts who developed gcc are absolutely not fresh-men like me, so I want to know why they didn't use Semaphore.
Just because it easily results buggy programs?
Guns and cannons might result invasion and death, but they might also be good tools for peace and balance.

This is my testing program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class FakeLock {
public:
   void lock() {};
   void unlock() {};
};

int                        g_iLoops = 1024;

condition_variable         g_cvsPing;
condition_variable_any     g_cvaPing;
sem_t                      g_semPing, g_semPong;

steady_clock::time_point   g_tpStart;
unique_ptr<uint64_t[]>     g_upBuffer;
uint64_t*                  g_puiElaps;
atomic_int64_t             g_aiPos = -1;

// thread body by means of CV
void thdCVS( int iMyId ) {
   /* Although a real lock is not required in many cases, but condition-
    * variable always needs one Arbitrarily. I think it's a small drawback,
    * because I believe std::mutex::lock() is a costly operation, especially
    * some time it must falls into busy checking.
    */
   mutex                mtxToken;
   unique_lock<mutex>   realLock( mtxToken );
   int iLast, iPos;
   iLast = iPos = g_aiPos;
   while ( iPos < g_iLoops ) {
      if ( ( iPos & 1 ) == iMyId ) {
         // phase 1 : as a sender
         // sleep a little while to ensure the peer has been listenning
         this_thread::sleep_for( 1us );

         g_tpStart = steady_clock::now();
         asm volatile( "mfence":::"memory" );
         g_aiPos.store( ( iLast = ++iPos ), memory_order_release );
         g_cvsPing.notify_one();
      } else {
         // phase 0 : as a listenner
         g_cvsPing.wait( realLock );
         iPos = g_aiPos.load( memory_order_acquire );
         asm volatile( "mfence":::"memory" );

         /* calculate only when iPos has been changed, since we might be
          * waked spuriously or the timeout be hitted.
          */
         if ( iPos > iLast && iPos < g_iLoops )
            g_puiElaps[ iPos ] = ( steady_clock::now() - g_tpStart ).count();
      }
   }
};

// thread body by means of CVA
void thdCVA( int iMyId ) {
   // Let's try condition_variable_any with a fake lock.
   FakeLock fakeLock;
   int iLast, iPos;
   iLast = iPos = g_aiPos;
   while ( iPos < g_iLoops ) {
      if ( ( iPos & 1 ) == iMyId ) {
         // phase 1 : as a sender
         // sleep a little while to ensure the peer has been listenning
         this_thread::sleep_for( 1us );

         g_tpStart = steady_clock::now();
         asm volatile( "mfence":::"memory" );
         g_aiPos.store( ( iLast = ++iPos ), memory_order_release );
         g_cvaPing.notify_one();
      } else {
         // phase 0 : as a listenner
         g_cvaPing.wait( fakeLock );
         iPos = g_aiPos.load( memory_order_acquire );
         asm volatile( "mfence":::"memory" );

         /* calculate only when iPos has been changed, since we might be
          * waked spuriously or the timeout hitted.
          */
         if ( iPos > iLast && iPos < g_iLoops )
            g_puiElaps[ iPos ] = ( steady_clock::now() - g_tpStart ).count();
      }
   }
};

// thread body by means of Semaphore
void thdSem( int iMyId ) {
   int iLast, iPos;
   iLast = iPos = g_aiPos;
   while ( iPos < g_iLoops ) {
      if ( ( iPos & 1 ) == iMyId ) {
         // phase 1 : as a sender
         // sleep a little while to keep fairness with thdCV
         this_thread::sleep_for( 1us );

         g_tpStart = steady_clock::now();
         asm volatile( "mfence":::"memory" );
         g_aiPos.store( ( iLast = ++iPos ), memory_order_release );
         sem_post( iMyId == 1 ? & g_semPing : & g_semPong );
      } else {
         // phase 0 : as a listenner
         sem_wait( iMyId == 0 ? & g_semPing : & g_semPong );
         iPos = g_aiPos.load( memory_order_acquire );
         asm volatile( "mfence":::"memory" );

         if ( iPos > iLast && iPos < g_iLoops )
            g_puiElaps[ iPos ] = ( steady_clock::now() - g_tpStart ).count();
      }
   }
   // notify the peer to exit
   // sem_post( & g_semPing );
};

double avgOf( const uint64_t* puiValues, int iCount,
              uint64_t& uiMax, uint64_t& uiMin );
double stdOf( const uint64_t* puiValues, int iCount, double dAvg );

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
   if ( argc < 2 ) {
      cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " loop_count " << endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   g_iLoops = atoi( argv[1] );
   g_upBuffer = make_unique<uint64_t[]>( g_iLoops );
   g_puiElaps = g_upBuffer.get();
   if ( sem_init( &g_semPing, 0, 0 ) || sem_init( &g_semPong, 0, 0 ) ) {
      cerr << "Failure when create a semaphore." << endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   uint64_t uiMax, uiMin;
   double dAvgElp, dStdDev;

   g_aiPos = -1;
   thread   thd0( thdCVS, 0 );
   this_thread::sleep_for( 1us );
   thread   thd1( thdCVS, 1 );
   thd0.join();
   thd1.join();
   dAvgElp = avgOf( g_puiElaps, g_iLoops, uiMax, uiMin );
   dStdDev = stdOf( g_puiElaps, g_iLoops, dAvgElp );
   cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 3 )
        << "Avg of CV is :" << dAvgElp / 1000   << "us" << endl
        << "StD is:"       << dStdDev / 1000    << "us" << endl
        << "Max delay is:" << uiMax / 1000      << "us" << endl
        << "Min delay is:" << uiMin / 1000      << "us" << endl
        << endl;

   g_aiPos = -1;
   thd0 = thread( thdCVA, 0 );
   this_thread::sleep_for( 1us );
   thd1 = thread( thdCVA, 1 );
   thd0.join();
   thd1.join();
   dAvgElp = avgOf( g_puiElaps, g_iLoops, uiMax, uiMin );
   dStdDev = stdOf( g_puiElaps, g_iLoops, dAvgElp );
   cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 3 )
        << "Avg of CVA is :" << dAvgElp / 1000  << "us" << endl
        << "StD is:"       << dStdDev / 1000    << "us" << endl
        << "Max delay is:" << uiMax / 1000      << "us" << endl
        << "Min delay is:" << uiMin / 1000      << "us" << endl
        << endl;

   g_aiPos = -1;
   thd0 = thread( thdSem, 0 );
   this_thread::sleep_for( 1us );
   thd1 = thread( thdSem, 1 );
   thd0.join();
   thd1.join();
   dAvgElp = avgOf( g_puiElaps, g_iLoops, uiMax, uiMin );
   dStdDev = stdOf( g_puiElaps, g_iLoops, dAvgElp );
   cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 3 )
        << "Avg of sem is :" << dAvgElp / 1000  << "us" << endl
        << "StD is:"       << dStdDev / 1000    << "us" << endl
        << "Max delay is:" << uiMax / 1000      << "us" << endl
        << "Min delay is:" << uiMin / 1000      << "us" << endl
        << endl;

   sem_destroy( &g_semPing );
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};

double avgOf( const uint64_t* puiValues, int iCount,
              uint64_t& uiMax, uint64_t& uiMin ) {
   double dTotal = uiMin = uiMax = puiValues[0];
   for ( int i = 1; i < iCount; ++i ) {
      dTotal += puiValues[i];
      uiMax = std::max<uint64_t>( uiMax, puiValues[i] );
      uiMin = std::min<uint64_t>( uiMin, puiValues[i] );
   }
   return dTotal / iCount;
};

double stdOf( const uint64_t* puiValues, int iCount, double dAvg ) {
   double dDiff, dSum = 0;
   for ( int i = 0; i < iCount; ++i ) {
      dDiff = puiValues[i] - dAvg;
      dSum += dDiff * dDiff;
   }
   return std::sqrt( dSum / iCount );
};
```

Comment: 1. `condition_variable` in libc++ on gcc on posix systems uses `pthread_cond_wait`. 2. Best in terms of what? Efficient on _your_ particular build and machine and OS? What about OS-es without pthread support but with C++ thread api?

Comment: "what is best" without exact specifications of what is the meaning of "best" is always opinion-based. Also its better to have one question per question

Comment: thank you two mind me , I will revise the title.

Comment: They are just different synchronization primitives. Btw., CVs are always used in a loop, so "notification lost"/"can not work with it smoothly" is not true (so your 1. and 2. point is not a real problem. About 3.: usually, a mutex is already needed, so it is not a real issue). Once you learn how to use CVs properly (yes, they are a little bit more difficult to understand than semaphores), they are no-brainer.